# Set data propert value from sequelize promise vue

Tags: vue.js, promise, electron, sequelize.js

I am using Vue, Electron and Sequelize, when I `npm run electron:serve`, sequelize promise doesn't return anything, data property won't set or show unless I save the code again to refresh the existing window:

```
<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            users : [],
        }
    },

    created () {
        console.log('created')
        this.fetchData();
    },

    methods: {
        fetchData () {
            let self = this
            let allUsers = db.User.findAll({
                attributes: ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password'], 
                raw : true
            }).then(res => {
                console.log('then working');
                self.users = res;
            }).catch(err  => {
                console.log('there was an error' + err)
            })
                console.log('fetchData method called' + allUsers)
        },
    }
</script>
```

I can see the fetchData() is being called but nothing show after .then( ... unless page is saved and refreshed.

[image: Text]

Comment: Are you not seeing 'then working' or 'there was an error' in the console?  If not, then the findAll isn't resolving or rejecting.  The 'fetchData method called' log is expected, and you shouldn't expect to see allUsers data there, since the find hasn't happened yet on that line

Comment: Thanks, yes I am not seeing resolve or error, I do release this is the problem I am trying to fix ... any ideas

Comment: Because findAll is async func and you don't use await you cannot use allUsers at the end of the function. Try to convert fetchData to async function

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the component data section. It doesn't have **users**:

```
 data () {
            dialog: false,
        }
```

All properties that should be reactive are declared in the data section of a component.